# How can i put all file IO record in my array successfully?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, file-io

I have a text file with default data that I created. Now I want to put them into my Array. But not success.. I dont know why only the first record of the struct data can store in my array.

I want first 9 records stored in Arr[0], secord 9 records stored in Arr[1] 
, and third 9 record stored in Arr[2] But the result is only recordNum can store in Arr[ I ].

I am very grateful and proud of you if you can help me because i try many time can not success

Here is my data file content:

```
1001 - bric - 1 - human - 10 - 70.00  - Eric - home - arrive

1002 - She  - 1 - human - 10 - 50.00  - she  - home - arrive

1003 - She  - 2 - human - 10 - 120.00 - Eric - home - arrived
```

Here is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct record{
   char recordnum [40];
   char itemrecord [40];
   char quantity [40];
   char weight [40];
   char itemname [40];
   char catagory [40];
   char recipient [40];
   char final_destination [40];
   char status [40];
};

int main(){
   FILE *fileptr1, *fileptr2, fileptr3;
   char filename[40]="data.txt";
   int save; 
   char delete_num ;
   char reply;
   int  n=1 , i=0;
   #define MAX 9
   struct record Arr[MAX];

   printf("Enter file name: ");
   scanf("%s", filename);

   //open file in read mode
   fileptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
   if (fileptr1== NULL){
      printf("open unsuccessful,file not exist"); 
      exit(1);
   }

   while(n>0){
      n=fscanf(fileptr1,"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",Arr[i].recordnum, 
      Arr[i].itemname, Arr[i].itemrecord, Arr[i].catagory, Arr[i].quantity, 
      Arr[i].weight, Arr[i].recipient, Arr[i].final_destination, 
      Arr[i].status ); 
      i++;
   }
   n=i;
   for(i=0; i<n-1 ;i++){
      printf("%s \n"  ,Arr[i]);
   }
   fclose(fileptr1);
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Enter file name: data.txt
1001
1002
1003
```

Comment: Review `printf("%s \n"  ,Arr[i]);`  Is `Arr[i]` a pointer to a _string_?  Tip: Enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: But no compiler warning and error here. @chux

Comment: Do not simply use default settings.  Enable _ALL_ warnings.  What compiler are you using?  And again: Is `Arr[i]` a pointer to a _string_?

Comment: Dev C++ ,btw sorry i am beginner

Comment: use char (*ptr)[N]  or I should define like: `char Arr[ i ]={recordnum, 
    itemname,catagory, quantity, 
    weight,recipient, final_destination, 
   status}`?? @chux

Comment: You should print each field of your struct one by one, printing a struct using `%s` format is undefined behaviour.

Comment: *Dev C++* – that is not a compiler but an IDE. But I guess you are using `gcc`. In Dev-C++ go to menu `[Tools]` ~> `[Compiler Options]` ~> tab `[Settings]` ~>  tab `[Warnings]` and enable `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, `-pedantic` and `-Werror`.

Comment: @Swordfish ok I do it .

Comment: @alamit let me research how to do it

Comment: @HangWui In the `[Compiler Options]` dialog is a dropdown `[Compiler set to configure]` ... you might want to do that for all compiler sets.

Comment: OK, I get this warning: [Warning] format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'struct record' [-Wformat=]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printf function's `"%s"` format is for strings. 
Strings in c are represented as one dimensional arrays (or a pointer to a portion of memory) containing characters and **ended by a '\0' character**.

Here you are trying to print a variable of type `struct record` with this format, which is undefined behaviour, in your example it happens that the bytes pointed by `Arr + i`(which is the address of the value `Arr[i]` of type `struct record`) are those of `Arr[i].recordnum`, therefore because you told printf to treat those bytes as string using the `"%s"` format, the characters are printed until a `'\0'` character is met. However, this is undefined behaviour because depending on architectures, structs might have padding bytes at the beginning instead of the bytes of their first field.

There is no printf format to print your custom struct, so you need to manually print each of your struct fields using their respective formats, in your case `%s`.

```
printf("%s, ..., %s\n", Arr[i].recordnum, ..., Arr[i].status);
```

Comment: that right. so my content is stored in my array successfully?

Comment: Yes @HangWui, but you should check it out by yourself to be sure.

Comment: Because i need to add delete function in my program, when I type the recordNum, whole rekevant record will be deleted @alamit

Comment: i have a concern about is there 9 record store in one i　？